# How to configure Maven/ant & Jenkins for multiple client parameter

Tags: java, maven, svn, ant, jenkins

At the very moment, i have 1 code base for all 7 client.  This code is currently manually deploy.  If i were to use Jenkins to deploy, any is there any documentation that points me on how to configure Maven/ant &Jenkins to solve the following 3 problems:

1. Each client has its own parameters and it is configure inside configuration files. Some is in text config properties, some has its very own parameter, some is inside XML and some is in a CSV.   Hence, i maintain a separate folder for each client in SVN.  Whenever i deploy, i make sure to copy the whole client configuration into the right path.
2. If new deployment, and since this is a console application, there is no web container to accept a war file and deflate. When i deploy a new whole application folder, and make sure the necessary open source jars are uploaded to the lib folder.
3. If existing upgrade deployment, i will only deploy the changed application jar, make sure to upload the new open source jars, any new folder(s) and keeping the existing folder untouch.

*Item number 2 seems to me is a one time job.  but i wonder if anything fancy in jenkins can make item 3 to behave like item 2 (eg: add but not replace)*?

Comment: Pro tip: most people answer questions here for internet points. When you have a 3-part question, where each part can be done in multiple ways, with no right or wrong answer, the chance of anyone answering all 3 to your satisfaction is small, so most will not bother at all. Break this up into smaller questions.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is not a magic button. It has a lot of great plugins, including some aimed at various deployments, but when you have a set of custom requirements (and yours are custom), you've got to write your own scripts (bash/batch) to achieve that with a combination of plugins.